SR Flip Flop using AND and NOR Gate as a Quiz Button
I was tasked of making SR Flip Flop circuit using AND and NOR Gate that behaves similarly to a SR Flip Flop of OR and NAND Gate.
Picture 1 is the example of the behavior I wish to emulate.

Picture 2 is my Failed Attempt of AND-NOR SR FLIP FLOP:

The Behavior I wish to see on picture 2 is:

If a Switch Button is pressed (SW1 or SW2) The nearest LED will light up but the farthest LED will not even if the other Switch Button is pressed and vice versa.
If SW3 Switch Button is Pressed, It will turn of LED 1 (D1) and LED 2 (D2) like a Reset Button.

Note: I was tasked only to use AND and NOR Gate instead of OR and NAND Gate. So I'll only breadboard to ICs (74LS02 and 74LS08).
Please include a Circuit Diagram of what I should fix if possible.

You've converted the logic on the inputs from active-low to active-high. You now need to connect your switches to +5V, and change the resistors to pull down to ground.
You also need to change how the two flip-flops are coupled to each other (for the same reason), but I'll leave it for you to work out the details.

The LEDs also need to be re-directed.

I don't know how to reconfigure the two flip flop to solve this circuit. I already tried the first one, adjusting the logic of the inputs.

If it isn't too much, can you provide any solution? I tried adjusting everything but it seems to be beyond my skill level.
